# Differences between p-value, level of significane and size of a test

Tags: statistical-significance, p-value

Can anybody tell me the differences between those quantities. As I know,
**p-value** is the minimum level of significance for a test to reject the null hypothesis with the observed data. 
**level of significane** is a number that is greater than or equal to the power function of the test among all possible values of the parameter when the null hypothesis is true.
**size of a test** is the maximum value of the power function of the test among all possible values of the parameter when the null hypothesis is true.
So **p-value** seems to be **size of a test** since they are both the minimum value of the **level of significance**. **Level of significane** seems to be **size of a test** since they're both a number that is greater or equal than the power function.
According to the inferences above, these three quantities refer to the same thing, can anybody show me the differences between them or correct me if I was wrong ?

Answer (score 5):

**level and size**

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Size_(statistics)) has the following:

> A test is said to have significance level $\alpha$ if its size is less than or equal to  $\alpha$.

I agree with this. It also says:

> the size of a test is [...] the probability of making a Type I error.

this is not quite always true. (It corrects it lower down in the article.)

In the case of a composite null hypothesis, the size is the supremum of the rejection rates over all the possibilities under the null.

Loosely, it's the largest rejection rate under the null.

Note that in the general case (ponder a potentially composite null and possibly discrete test statistic) we may not be able to actually attain a rejection rate of some pre-specified $\alpha$

- e.g. consider a two-tailed sign test with n=18 -- you can get a rejection rate under the null of 3.1% or 9.6% but you can't actually get 5% unless you resort to devices like randomized tests, or
- consider that the actual type I error rate may depend on where in the null we happen to be situated. For example, with a one-sided t-test where $H_0: \mu\leq 0$, if the true $\mu=-0.5$ the type $I$ error rate will generally be lower than it would be if $\mu=-0.03$.

So now consider I want a significance level of 5% with *one* tailed sign test with $n=18$ under the composite null $H_0: \tilde{\mu}\leq 0$ vs $H_1:\tilde{\mu}> 0$. Now if $\tilde{\mu}$ is actually $0$ then my type I error rate is just over 4.8%. On the other hand if $\tilde{\mu}$ is $<0$ then my type I error rate will be something smaller than 4.8%; lets say we are in a particular situation under the null (depending on the specifics of the distribution) and our type I error rate there is 3.2%. We'd have a test with a 5% significance level, a size of 4.81% and an actual type I error rate of 3.2% (though in practice we couldn't figure this last one out because we wouldn't *know* either the population shape or its median).

Note *in particular* that both size and level don't relate to the sample -- if we draw another random sample of the same size (and other relevant characteristics), we should not expect size or level to change.

---

**p value**

The p-value is the probability of obtaining a test statistic at least as extreme as the one we observed from the sample, if the null hypothesis were true.

So by contrast with the other two things, the p-value is a function of the *sample*. New sample, new p-value.

It may be less than or greater than the the type I error rate, the size or the significance level.

Comment: Hi @Glen_b. In general, the p-value calculated by the sample is the smallest significance level such that we would reject the null hypothesis with the observed data. It seems to me that p-value is equal to the size of a test. If not, could you point out the difference between them? Thanks.

Comment: What definition are you using for "size of a test"?

Comment: size of a test is the maximum value of the power function of the test among all possible values of the parameter when the null hypothesis is true.

Comment: Sure, but the power function is just the rejection rate, so the highest rejection rate under the null. Notice that the definition of the size makes no reference whatever to the sample (as I discuss in my answer), while the p-value *does* (again, per my answer). Size is a property of the *test* you're going to conduct -- you know what it is before you collect your data, it's a function of the null hypothesis, the assumptions, the statistic and the rejection rule. The p-value, by contrast, *is* a property of the sample (indeed, it's a statistic). You only know it after you collect the data.

Comment: Really enjoyed this answer. Thanks for sharing. Are you able to give some more detail about the calculations used? I'm not sure where these numbers are coming from? Specifically, the 3.1% and the 9.6%? I looked up the values for a T test, but I can't see any obvious connection with the numbers you used? Thanks!

Comment: The 3.1% and the 9.6% are for a *sign* test (the exact [binomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) null distribution for the test statistic, not a normal approximation). Since it's discrete, you usually can't actually attain 5%. For n=18, it  turns out that when H0 is true the possible two-tailed rejection rates that sit closest either side of 5% happen when $\min(n_+,n_-)$ are 4 and 5 respectively, giving the rejection rates mentioned.  In R, `pbinom(4:5,18,0.5)*2` will give ` 0.03088379 0.09625244`  rounding to 3.1% and 9.6%. Use `qbinom(.025,18,.5)` to see where to look

Comment: Or for a small problem like this one, just print the entire distribution and find it by inspection. Excel (and indeed other popular spreadsheets) can do an equivalent calculation to `pbinom`. To actually carry out the sign test in R at those specific values for the test statistic, there's `binom.test(4,18,0.5)` (and similarly for 5) . You can try these snippets of code at `rdrr.io/snippets`  ... paste any of them in place of the code in the code window and hit the big green Run button

Comment: Thank you so much. This was super helpful!

Comment: +1, it's not always easy to make the distinction between size - significant level - type I error. Am I right to say that if you deal with a continuous distribution and "pointwise" null hypothesis (e.g. $H_0=\mu_0$), then all coïncide ? In fact size and significant level differ when discrete law is considered; size and type I error when $H_0$ is composite ?

Comment: Yes, aside any use of conservative tests I think with a point null and a continuous random variable that in practice it's always going to be the case that they're the same; this is probably why they're often conflated, given that things like point null t-tests and ANOVA with continuous variables etc are mostly what's taught in beginner classes. You could of course set something up where one of those things differed but that would be dominated by another test where they didn't; if you had some setup where your rejection rule was conservative, it should be possible to change the rejection rule